# Insert tag <div> before and after tag <img>

Tags: html, jquery

this my case

```
<p>
  <img src="myimage.jpg">
</p>
```

I would like to add  tag before and after

end result:

```
<p>
  <div>
    <img src="myimage.jpg">
  </div>
</p>
```

this case custom by cms and I need to handle image size

Comment: `$("img").parent().append("<div>");$("img").append("</div>");`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**.wrap()**](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of
>   matched elements.

```js
$('p > img').wrap('<div class="img_wrapper"></div>');
```

```css
.img_wrapper{
  background : red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding : 5px;
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
}
.img_wrapper > img{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100X200">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150X300">
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.append()` and `.appendTo()` methods as follows:

```js
$('<div/>').append($('img')).appendTo('p');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="myimage.jpg">
</p>
```